# How do I remove map annotations in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit

In this Swift code, I am using MapKit to get a map. By default, there are map annotations like shops, restaurants, petrol stations etc. I want to remove these annotations.

I know there are simple solutions for iOS 17, but the deployment target of this project is iOS 15. I need a solution that works on iOS 15.

How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct MapView: View {
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: .init(latitude: 37.334_900,longitude: -122.009_020),
        span: .init(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(region), showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: .constant(.follow))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .onAppear {
                    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related but `.constant` is only for previews don't use it in the `body`.